# Using the dynamic Type to receive complex objects in C# REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, dynamic, binding

I have the following code

```
[HttpPost]
public void ImportUsers(dynamic parameters)
{
   ImportSourceCredentials importSourceCredentials = ((JObject)parameters.importSourceCredentials).ToObject<ImportSourceCredentials>();
   IEnumerable<string> externalIds = ((JArray)parameters.externalIds).ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>();
   ...
   ...
}
```

Is there a problem here that the two complex objects are received as a dynamic type (in the request body) and deserialized manually?

Is there a strong case to use a DTO object to take advantage of the automatic binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three reasons for not using dynamic type:

1. Security reasons. Please investigate on JSON Injection. It used to be a problem for some marshallers some time ago. Tldr dynamics faciliate remote code execution. [Here is example with further readings](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html)

---

Following two are more general, not exactly applying to your implementation.

2. Later on when project grows you will have trouble remembering what kind of data the controller accepts. If it is a part of microservice architecture it will tamper reading the code as you will have no hint as to what could send data to that (which would be possible with application wide DTOs, VS would show you references)
3. Some bugs are moved to runtime e.g typo in some field accessor, that would be caught by compiler if dto was used would crash application in runtime with dynamic type.

My advice is to minimize use of dynamic type as much as possible. C# is statically typed, so why discard it?